# How can i implement tabs using Razor Page Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-3.1

How to implement multiple forms using Bootstrap Tabs and Razor Page Models.
Currently im using Bootstrap Tabs and Partial Views for implementing this.
Now whats the problem is i have about 8 forms to fill out so maintaining all the server side actions in a single page is messy.
Could someone guide me in this.
this is how my page looks like.
[image]

This is how my folder structure looks like
[image]

The file name highlighted in Yellow color will having the navigation tabs.

So **StaffOnboarding.cshtml** will like this.

```
@page
@model Contractor_HRMS.Pages.Staff.Onboarding.StaffOnboardingModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Staff Onboarding";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h4>STAFF ONBOARDING</h4>
<hr />

<div>
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link 
               href="/Staff/Onboarding/StaffDetails">StaffDetails</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link 
               href="/Staff/Onboarding/Biodata">Biodata</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link 
               href="/Staff/Onboarding/EduQualification">EduQualification</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link 
               href="/Staff/Onboarding/Assets">Assets</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

By default it should load the contents in StaffDetails Page.and when i click save button it should save the details and able to move on to next tab.
when i click on other tabs it should render the html contents of respective forms.

Comment: What does your code look like? What server side actions are you referring to? My assumption is that the Bootstrap Tabs are implemented on the client side, and your form is distributed between multiple tabs. But the fact that you're talking about centralizing the tabs via a Partial View makes me wonder if you're instead treating each tab's form as a separate page and doing e.g. a postback when the user clicks each tab? Can you clarify your requirements and provide some sample code?

Comment: @Jeremy Caney can i use razor page models for each form?when i click on 'StaffDetails' tab it should go to the razor page  of 'StaffDetails' but all other tabs should be there.Currently i have not implemented with this logic,now im handling this with pagehandlers and partial view.

Comment: I don't see why not, if that's the preferred implementation. But I'm not really understanding what the question is. Is the issue that you need to submit a post when clicking between tabs to ensure that your current form is saved? Or, perhaps, that you want to establish a centralized view model for binding the tab labels and URLs to? Maybe writing some pseudocode of what you're hoping to accomplish might help.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I have edited my question.Please have a look and let me know if you are still unclear about my requirement.Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now whats the problem is i have about 8 forms to fill out so maintaining all the server side actions in a single page is messy.

You can have a razor page for each tab. I made an example like below:

These are the razor pages:

[image]

And I use Unobtrusive AJAX to submit the form. You should download it to your project and reference it in your page:

[image]

**StaffOnboarding.cshtml( The main view ):**

```
@page
@model WebApplication4.Pages.Staff.Onboarding.StaffOnboardingModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Staff Onboarding";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h4>STAFF ONBOARDING</h4>
<hr />

<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="StaffDetails"
               href="#StaffDetails">StaffDetails</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="Biodata"
               href="#Biodata">Biodata</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="EduQualification"
               href="#EduQualification">EduQualification</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="Assets"
               href="#Assets">Assets</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="StaffDetails" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Biodata" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="EduQualification" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Assets" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">

    </div>
</div>


@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Staff/Onboarding/StaffDetails",
                type: "get",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#StaffDetails").html(result);
                }
            })

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Staff/Onboarding/Biodata",
                type: "get",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#Biodata").html(result);
                }
            })

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Staff/Onboarding/EduQualification",
                type: "get",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#EduQualification").html(result);
                }
            })

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Staff/Onboarding/Assets",
                type: "get",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#Assets").html(result);
                }
            })
        })

        function firstCompleted() {
            $('a[href="#Biodata"]').tab('show');
        }
        function secondCompleted() {
            $('a[href="#EduQualification"]').tab('show');
        }
        function thirdCompleted() {
            $('a[href="#Assets"]').tab('show');
        }
        function forthCompleted() {
            alert("All Submit")
        }
    </script>
}
```

**StaffDetails.cshtml:**

```
@page
@model WebApplication4.Pages.Staff.Onboarding.StaffDetailsModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h1>StaffDetails</h1>
<form asp-page-handler="Assests" 
      data-ajax="true"
      data-ajax-method="post"
      data-ajax-complete="firstCompleted">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**StaffDetails.cshtml.cs:**

```
public class StaffDetailsModel : PageModel
{
    public ActionResult OnGet()
    {
        
    }
    public void OnPost()
    {
        //do some stuff 
    }
}
```

For simplicity, I used the same layout as StaffDetails.cshtml for the other pages. What needs to be changed is `data-ajax-complete=""`, each form has a independent completed function.

**Update:**

I set the `[Required]` attribute on the model proerties to make them required.

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

StaffDetails.cshtml:

```
@page
@model WebApplication4.Pages.Staff.Onboarding.StaffDetailsModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h1>StaffDetails</h1>
<form asp-page-handler="StaffDetails" 
        data-ajax="true"
        data-ajax-method="post"
        data-ajax-complete="firstCompleted">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.user.Email">
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.user.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.user.Password">
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.user.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And in the page handler, determine if it is vaild when submit the form.

```
public class StaffDetailsModel : PageModel
{
    public User user { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        
    }
    public IActionResult OnPost(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return new OkResult();
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Then in ajax completed method, determine whether to move to the next tab or display the verification information of the form under the current tab by the returned data.

```
function firstCompleted(event) {
    if (event.responseText != "") {
        $("#StaffDetails").html(event.responseText);
    } else {
        $('a[href="#Biodata"]').tab('show');
    }
}

function secondCompleted(event) {
    if (event.responseText != "") {
        $("#Biodata").html(event.responseText);
    } else {
        $('a[href="#EduQualification"]').tab('show');
    }
}

function thirdCompleted(event) {
    if (event.responseText != "") {
        $("#EduQualification").html(event.responseText);
    } else {
        $('a[href="#Assets"]').tab('show');
    }
}

function forthCompleted(event) {
    if (event.responseText != "") {
        $("#Assets").html(event.responseText);
    } else {
        alert("All Submit")
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have one problem now,my remote validations are not working.When form is submitted its redirecting to next tab without validating anything.Do i need to add any ajax scripts for validation?

Comment: i have added jquery validations and jquery validations unobtrusive.Still its not displaying the remote validations error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Now the validation is working. How can i validate user input on the server without posting the entire form .Now the error messages are still showing after key in the data into input fields . How to enable the remote validations?

Comment: Hi @Teena, you can try to add `<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />` in each page.

Comment: Hi ,i have added that in Staffonboarding.cshtml page.I thought other pages are calling from this master page then this would be fine.Will change it and check and will let you know.Thanks!

Comment: Hi mj1313,its working fine.Thank you so much for the support !

Comment: Hi mj1313, how can i display already existing staffdetails in the form?Currently i will be having a Directory page,where already entered staff details will be displaying with edit and delete anchor tags.So when you click on the edit link,it should prepopulate the details of respective staff in the forms.Currently i have passed the id using asp-page-route and in the get method i wrote the LINQ query to display it.But nothing is displaying now.

Comment: Hi @Teena, maybe you can open a new thread and details the question.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I will start a new thread for this.

Comment: Hi @mj1313 Here is my new thread  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65146409/razor-pages-with-multiple-tabs-that-prepopulate-already-inserted-data

Comment: Hi @mj1313 could you please explain me meaning of this code snippet 'return new OkResult()'  .What does this OkResult() refers to.Can i use anyother word for this?

Comment: @Teena It is a StatusCodeResult that when executed will produce `an empty Status200OK response.` I use it here because I get the response in the completed function, the responseText will be null if it return new OkResult(), then it will go next tab.Of course you can return other classes that intended from [ActionResult](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/action-results), it just depend on how do you deal with the repsonse in the front end.

Comment: @Thanks for clarifying my doubt. One more doubt,if my form has file to upload,do i need to use ajax attribute for that or this code snippet is enough 'enctype="multipart/form-data" '?

Comment: @Teena have a try first .

Comment: Hi need one help,how can i pass EmpID and StaffID from StaffDetails page to Biodata page.I used TempData for assigning value to hidden input in Biodata page.But its not working.Do i need to pass the StaffID and EmpID in ajax ?